# Auto suggestion in search view but not using content provider

Tags: android, searchview, autosuggest

I want to add auto suggestion in my search view (which is not in the action bar), this suggestions comes from a GET API call. I parse the response to a POJO class.
Now, is it necessary to store the suggestion in a content provider? Or I can use the POJO class itself, if I can, how?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show your current adapter.

Comment: Are you using "http://gd.geobytes" api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Textwatcher for this..

```
searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 2) {
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL("api call")
                            // fetch and show the result
                            }
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            Log.e(((Object) this).getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(((Object) this).getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(((Object) this).getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I think this is what you want..

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you:**

```
FilterEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //hide or show close icon based on text entered
        try {

            if (s.length() == 0) {
           //not typed anything in the search box then load the adapter with default values or empty

                initializeAdapter(mAirportCity);


            } 
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        //If user enters text to search, then call the api with entered text
        onSearchTextChanged(s.toString());
    }
};

public void onSearchTextChanged(String searchTxt) {
    if (searchTxt == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(searchTxt) || searchTxt.length() < 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        String url = "Your Base URL";
        url= url + searchTxt.trim().replace(" ", "%20");
            CJRVolley.getRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(new CJRGsonGetRequest(url,
                    this, this, "Your Model Class here", null));

    }
}


 @Override
public void onResponse(IJRDataModel response) {

        //in onresponse initialize the adapter here
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Naveen. But I am not using a textView, I am using a search view and addTextChangedListener doesn't apply, setOnQueryTextListener does. And my question is, what after I have called the API of auto suggest in onQueryTextChange, how can I display the auto suggestion? As it is not a AutoCompleteTextView  and search view takes only cursorAdapter and I don't want to use a content provider. Thanks again! :)